# How do you process binary files in Python

Tags: java, python, file, file-io

We had *DataInputStream* for processing binary files in Java; what can we use for these files in Python?

Comment: read this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035340/reading-binary-file-in-python and this one too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710456/reading-a-binary-file-with-python

Comment: Does you code need to be compatible with DataInputStream's file format?

Answer (score 2):

I have used the [Construct](http://construct.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) package a lot to read and parse structures data in Python.

Basically it lets you declare the file's structure in a very idiomatic and pythonic way and than parses or encode it for you.

After parsing you have an object that allows access to all the file's information via attributes.

Answer (score 1):

`open("file", "b")` opens the file and you can read it. See [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open).

Answer (score 1):

Few years ago I used struct module to parse binary responses from several game servers http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#struct.unpack

Sometimes it's usefull just to `.find()` some bytes in data, like `.find('\x00')` to go to the end of NULL-terminated string.