# Reading camera input from /dev/video0 in python or c

Tags: python, c, linux

I want to read from the file /dev/video0 either through c or python,and store the incoming bytes in a different file.
Here is my c code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
int main()
{
    int fd,wfd;
    fd=open("/dev/video0",O_RDONLY);
    wfd=open("image",O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_APPEND,S_IRWXU);
    if(fd==-1)
        perror("open");
    while(1)
    {
        char buffer[50];
        int rd;
        rd=read(fd,buffer,50);
        write(wfd,buffer,rd);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When i run this code and after some time terminate the program nothing happens except a file name "image" is generated which is usual.

This is my python code:

```
    image=open("/dev/video0","rb")
    image.read()
```

and this is my error when my run this snippet:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

I want to know how to do this using pure c or python code.Please no external library suggestions.

Comment: Is it possible you need to open the camera in read/write mode and send a command to enable it?

Comment: @AndrewCorsini well i think i should be possible.And why not?

Comment: "This is my python code: `image=open("/dev/video0","rb") image.readline()`": `readline()` is used for text lines terminated in '\n'. Since you read binary data, use read(). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710456/reading-a-binary-file-with-python

Comment: @boardrider with read also it is giving  the same error.

Comment: If you save the video stream to a file on disk (AVI or MP4), and then just change the `open()` to use that file, does all work as expected?

Comment: @boardrider No, it does not work.

Comment: @boardrider I want to know what type of argument does read require.

Comment: There's a very good chance that my example, given in an answer, will be _down-voted_ as *not answering the question*, but since I cannot add _formatted Python code_ inside of a comment - I'll suffer the points loss for the greater good :-)

Comment: you need to use a library for that. you can't just do that

Answer (score 2):

It's not so easy.

1. Most cameras won't work in read/write mode. You need to use [Streaming I/O mode](http://linuxtv.org/downloads/v4l-dvb-apis/io.html#rw) - for example memory mapping.
2. You need to set [pixel format](http://linuxtv.org/downloads/v4l-dvb-apis/pixfmt.html) - YUYV/RGB/MJPEG, bytes per pixel, resolution.
3. You have to start grabbing, read and save at least one frame.

Answer (score 1):

Further to my comment, here's an example of displaying a video stream from video on disk (see [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=videowriter)):

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

video = "../videos/short.avi"

video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(video)

while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()

    # Our operations on the frame comes here
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything's done, release the capture
video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```