# Python.. convert bin/hex file to txt file

Tags: python

I want to convert a bin file to txt file in python.

```
with open("atb.bin", "rb") as file:

     data = file.read(8)

datastring = str(data)

print(datastring)
print(' '.join(str(ord(c)) for c in datastring))
```

The output I get is

```
b'\x14\x12\x1c\x1a#\x00-d'
98 39 92 120 49 52 92 120 49 50 92 120 49 99 92 120 49 97 35 92 120 48 48 45 100 39
```

Now, how do I convert this to decimal and store in a txt file?

Comment: don't convert your bytes object to string... python 2 or python 3?

Comment: Its Python 3.Can you please suggest a solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading a binary file with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710456/reading-a-binary-file-with-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your main mistake is doing:

```
datastring = str(data)
```

As it converts the representation of the `data` object to string, with `b` prefix and quotes, and escaping... *wrong*.

read your file as you're doing:

```
with open("atb.bin", "rb") as file:
     data = file.read(8)
```

now `data` is a `bytes` object, no need for `ord` in python 3, values are already integer. Now open a text file and dump the values (converting integers to string, decimal):

```
with open("out.txt", "w") as f:
   f.write(" ".join(map(str,data))):
   f.write("\n")
```

In python 2 you'd need to get the character code *then* convert to string:

```
   f.write(" ".join([str(ord(c)) for c in data]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Python converts into text, the text representation of the 8 characters in the file.

Hence, instead of

```
print(' '.join(str(ord(c)) for c in datastring))
```

you should have put

```
print(' '.join(str(ord(c)) for c in data))
```

which you can then write to a file using standard techniques.

ie.
(Python 2)

```
>>> data=b'\x14\x12\x1c\x1a#\x00-d'
>>> print(' '.join(str(ord(c)) for c in data))
20 18 28 26 35 0 45 100
```

(Python 3)

```
>>> data=b'\x14\x12\x1c\x1a#\x00-d'
>>> print(' '.join(str(c) for c in data))
20 18 28 26 35 0 45 100
```

Comment: Can we use struct.unpack() in this case? In which scenarios the unpack is useful?