# Converting a long string of bits as nibbles to decimal in Python

Tags: python, string, binary

I have a very long string of bits (500 bits of 0s and 1s only). How do I convert this to decimal in sets of 4 (i.e a nibble of 4 bits)?

I tried the following approach, but it doesn't work (followed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49676043/python-convert-bin-hex-file-to-txt-file))

```
with open("atb.bat","rb") as file:   # atb.bat is the file which contains the string
    data=file.read(4)
with open("out.txt","w") as f:
    f.write(" ".join(map(str,data)))
    f.write("\n")
```

I expect the output to be 125 integers but end up with only 4 decimal values!

I also tried something like this

```
p1 = 100000001111100101110011001101100110010 # (for example)
p22 =np.packbits(p1,axis=0)
```

but doesn't work!

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert strings out of 0's and 1's by the `int(inputstring, 2)`method:
[Convert base-2 binary number string to int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8928240/convert-base-2-binary-number-string-to-int)

So loop over your long inputstring , take 4 chars (which you can do like explained here [Split string every nth character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475241/split-string-every-nth-character)) an pass them to the int() method. Then concat/join the output to a loong outputstring.

Answer (score 0):

```
nn = 4    
p12_ = [int(p1[i:i+nn],2) for i in range(0, len(p1), nn)]
```