# Binary stream in python

Tags: python, object, stream, binary, blob

I am having a hard time recreating this code in **python**:

```
dtoIn.inputFile = new Blob([JSON.stringify({ financialTransactionList })], { type: "application/json" });
```

API only takes files as blob files and I am not sure how to convert pdf files into binary streams. So I tried to convert it using the IO library but I am not having the same result as in JS

```
    with open(file_destination, "rb", buffering=0) as pdf_file:
        binary = BytesIO(pdf_file.read())
```

How to do it right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading a binary file with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710456/reading-a-binary-file-with-python). First part of the first answer should be what you are looking for. `BytesIO` is not necessary in this case, simply `pdf_file.read()` (`binary` will be of type `bytes`).

Comment: I am sorry mate, it didn't. Thanks for the help anyway. I ended up rewriting the whole project because of this.