# How can I write binary file in C with different types of variables and read in Python that?

Tags: python, c, binary, readfile, fwrite

Until now I save a file with a "csv" format in C. However, the size of files are large, so execution time in I/O step is very long for me. Thus, I tried to save a binary file in C, but, some garbage data are inserted when reading a file in Python.

The types of data in file are same for below:

```
int double int double double ...
```

I tried in C

```
...

FILE* fp_result = fopen([filepath]); // the file format is .bin

double w[60];
double th[60];

...

int n = 0;
double K = 10.0;
int num = 30;

fwrite(&n, sizeof(int), 1, fp_result);
fwrite(&K, sizeof(double), 1, fp_result);
fwrite(&num, sizeof(int), 1, fp_result);
fwrite(w, sizeof(double), 60, fp_result);
fwrite(th, sizeof(double), 60, fp_result);

fclose(fp_result);
```

And then I tried in Python

```
import numpy as np

x = np.fromfile([filepath])
print(x)
```

the result is

```
array[0, 1e-365, ..., 10e0, ...]
```

how can I solve this problem?

Comment: `fromfile` needs to know the `dtype` which can be a structure of different data types. See [Structured Arrays](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.rec.html)

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
fwrite(n, sizeof(int), 1, fp_result);
fwrite(K, sizeof(double), 1, fp_result);
fwrite(num, sizeof(int), 1, fp_result);
```

will promptly crash. You want:

```
fwrite(&n, sizeof(int), 1, fp_result);
fwrite(&K, sizeof(double), 1, fp_result);
fwrite(&num, sizeof(int), 1, fp_result);
```

You'll also want to enable *maximum* compiler warnings (`-Wall -Wextra` if using GCC), so the compiler tells you about the bug above.

After fixing that, all you'll have to do is thread the binary data in Python. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8711061/50617).

Comment: Ah.. I missed the "&" symbol before a variable when I wrote this post. However, in actual code I included "&" symbol. thanks!

Comment: @lksj And this is why you cut/paste your _actual_ code, and not some mangled version of it.

Comment: @EmplyedRussian Yeah.. I forgot it for a moment.. Thank you for reminding me of that.